# Como inicializar automaticamente os atributos has_many no Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relacionamento

Atualmente eu tenho 3 model

```
class Regiao < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tipofretes
  has_many :valorfretes, through: :tipofretes
end

class Tipofrete < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :regiao
  has_many :valorfretes, through: :regiaofretes
end

class Valorfrete < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :regiao
  belongs_to :tipofrete
end
```

No *Model* TipoFrete existe 5 registros que inicialmente serão padrões do sistema.

Minha dúvida é, quando eu for criar/salvar uma Regiao automaticamente carrega os registros do TipoFretes e save no banco de dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só para deixar para aqueles que estarão com o mesmo problema que o meu.

Primeiramente eu fiz o mapeamento errado. O correto é;

```
class Regiaofrete < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :valorfretes
  has_many :tipofretes, through: :valorfretes

  validates :descricao, presence:  true
end


class Tipofrete < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :valorfretes
  has_many :regiaofretes, through: :valorfretes
end

class Valorfrete < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :regiaofrete
  belongs_to :tipofrete
end
```

inverti os has_many

Para iniciar os registro tem que ser a nível do Controller

```
def new
    @regiaofrete = Regiaofrete.new
    @regiaofrete.tipofretes << Tipofrete.all
end
```

O operador **<<** adiciona objetos a uma ***list*** ou ***array***

Comment: Marque sua resposta como correta para colocá-la em primeiro e indicar aos usuários que é esta a resposta que responde a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

O Rails possuí uma padronização para popular o seu banco de dados, essa padronização serve para manter a manutenção do seu app. Não sei como são as colunas de seu banco de dados, então postarei um modelo genérico:

Dentro da pasta do seu projeto Rails, você terá o seguinte arquivo: `db/seed.rb`, esse é o arquivo responsável por popular seu banco de dados.

Você pode inserir dados da seguinte maneira:

```
# This file should contain all the record creation needed to seed the database with its default values.
# The data can then be loaded with the rake db:seed (or created alongside the db with db:setup).
#
# Examples:
#
#   cities = City.create([{ name: 'Chicago' }, { name: 'Copenhagen' }])
#   Mayor.create(name: 'Emanuel', city: cities.first)

##
    Departament.create(name: 'Poltronas', subtitle:'', slug: 'poltronas', description: '')
    Departament.create(name: 'Puffs', subtitle:'', slug: 'puffs', description: '')
    Departament.create(name: 'Sofás', subtitle:'', slug: 'sofas', description: '')
    Departament.create(name: 'Chaises', subtitle:'', slug: 'chaises', description: '')
    Departament.create(name: 'Banquetas', subtitle:'', slug: 'banquetas', description: '')
    Departament.create(name: 'Office', subtitle:'', slug: 'office', description: '')
    Departament.create(name: 'Cadeiras', subtitle:'', slug: 'cadeiras', description: '')
    Departament.create(name: 'Mesas', subtitle:'', slug: 'mesas', description: '')
    Departament.create(name: 'Itens', subtitle:'', slug: 'itens', description: '')
    Departament.create(name: 'Pronta Entrega', subtitle:'', slug: 'pronta-entrega', description: 'Conheça nossos produtos disponíveis a pronta entrega')
```

Você também pode usar iterações no mesmo, exemplo:

```
5.times do |i|
  Product.create(name: "Product ##{i}", description: "A product.")
end
```

Para aplicar a sua popularização basta entrar em seu terminal na pasta de seu projeto com o comando:

```
rake db:seed
```

Existem pessoas que incluem essas popularizações em `Migrations` também...

```
class AddInitialProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    5.times do |i|
      Product.create(name: "Product ##{i}", description: "A product.")
    end
  end

  def down
    Product.delete_all
  end
end
```

Comment: Sim, eu coloquei os registros padrão do Tipofrete no seed, pois estes seram praticamente fixos.  O meu o meu problema era nas Regiaofrete pois essas são dinamicas e pode ter 1..N. Minha dúvida era, quando se cria um região automaticamente se cria os ValoreFrete, uma para cada Tipofrete.

Comment: Pelo o que você explicou pra você adicionar uma Região você precisa ter um Tipo já pré-cadastrado(seed), correto? Usando o seed você já terá os tipos cadastrados e depois a pessoa seleciona o tipo para a região. Não era isso? :)